# put two or more buttons in one column in Tabolator Javascript lib

Tags: javascript, tabulator

as title i want to make a column like this

[image]

if i press editBt,
editBt and delBt will change to updateBt and cancelBt in the same column
and the row will be editable

if press or updateBt or cancelBt,
updateBt and cancelBt will change back to editBt and delBt
and the row will be readonly

i've been told by some way to do it like:

```js
{
    title : "",
    field : "functionButton",
    width : 100,
    visible : true,
    formatter : function(cell) {
            return '<button type="button" class="btn-edit" onclick="editRow(this); return false;">editBt</button>'
                 + '<button type="button" class="btn-del" onclick="delRow(this); return false;">delBt</button>' 
                 + '<button type="button" class="btn-update" onclick="updateRow(this); return false;">updateBt</button>'
                 + '<button type="button" class="btn-cancel" onclick="cancelRow(this); return false;">cancelBt</button>'
    }
},
```

but then i cant use functions lib provided (editable row)

is there any way to do this or alternative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with i am going to assume that the ***editRow***, ***delRow***, ***updateRow*** and ***cancelRow*** functions outlined in your example are external functions that you have already coded as they are not part of Tabulator.

Rather than returning static HTML from the formatter, it would be better to create the button elements using `document.createElement()` and then binding event listeners to them, you can then pass the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-cell) or [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-row) into your other functions, which will give you full control over the row, passing `this` into your functions would pass the whole table object, which would not help you in knowing which row was being edited.

```js
function(cell) {

    //create edit button
    var editBt = document.createElement("button");
    editBt.type = "button";
    editBt.textContent = "editBt";
    editBt.classList.add("btn-edit");
    editBt.addEventListener("click", function(){
       editRow(cell);
    });
    
    //create delete button
    var delBt= document.createElement("button");
    delBt.type = "button";
    delBt.textContent = "delBt";
    delBt.classList.add("btn-del");
    delBt.addEventListener("click", function(){
       delRow(cell);
    });
   
    //create update button
    var updateBt = document.createElement("button");
    updateBt.type = "button";
    updateBt.textContent = "updateBt";
    updateBt.classList.add("btn-update");
    updateBt.addEventListener("click", function(){
       updateRow(cell);
    });

    //create cancel button
    var cancelBt = document.createElement("button");
    cancelBt.type = "button";
    cancelBt.textContent = "editBt";
    cancelBt.classList.add("btn-cancel");
    cancelBt.addEventListener("click", function(){
       cancelRow(cell);
    });
 
    //add buttons to cell (just the edit and delete buttons to start with)
    var buttonHolder = document.createElement("span");
    buttonHolder.appendChild(editBt); 
    buttonHolder.appendChild(delBt); 
 
    return buttonHolder;
}
```

Inside the `addEventListener` function for each of the buttons you could then add logic to add and remove other buttons as needed. For example to make clicking the edit but show the update and cancel buttons:

```js
editBt.addEventListener("click", function(){

    //hide edit and delete buttons
    editBt.parentNode.removeChild(editBt);
    updateBt.parentNode.removeChild(updateBt);

    //add update and cancel buttons
    buttonHolder.appendChild(updateBt);
    buttonHolder.appendChild(cancelBt);

    editRow(cell); //call your original function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but for those wanting to edit one Tabulator row in a modal window (or popup), here I add one possibility with actual working code:

I am using Tabulator 5.5

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Notify, Confirms } from "./notify";
import { Tabulator, AjaxModule, FormatModule } from 'tabulator-tables'
import '../../node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   let dataRow = {}

   Tabulator.registerModule([AjaxModule, FormatModule])
   var table = new Tabulator("#grid", {
      ajaxURL: "/dashboard/getProducts",
      index: "productId",
      height: "308px",
      placeholder: "No data available",
      autoResize: true,
      columns: [
         { title: "pId", field: "productId", visible: false },
         { title: "Code", field: "productCode", width: 90 },
         { title: "Description", field: "description", width: 450 },
         { title: "Category", field: "categoryId" },
         { title: "Price", field: "price", width: 90 },
         { title: "Brand", field: "brandId" },
         {
            title: "Actions", formatter: function(cell, formatterParams) {
               return "<button class='editBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-success'>Edit</button>&nbsp;<button class='delBtn btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger'>Delete</button>";
            }
         }
      ],
      footerElement: "<button id='addProduct' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#myModal'>Add product</button>",
   })

   
   // Edit and delete buttons event handlers.
   document.getElementById('grid').addEventListener('click', e => {
     const editBtn = e.target.closest('.editBtn')
     const delBtn = e.target.closest('.delBtn')
     let selectedRow = e.target.closest('div.tabulator-row')

     // Check if a row was clicked...
     if (selectedRow !== null) {
        var gridRow = table.getRow(selectedRow.children[0].innerText)
        dataRow = gridRow.getData()

        if (editBtn !== null) {
           var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'))
           myModal.show()

           // Change modal title.
           document.getElementById('staticBackdropLabel').innerText = 'Actualizar producto'

           // Load form inputs with dataRow values.
           document.getElementById('productCode').value = dataRow.productCode
           document.getElementById('description').value = dataRow.description
           document.getElementById('categoryId').value = dataRow.categoryId
           document.getElementById('price').value = dataRow.price
           document.getElementById('brandId').value = dataRow.brandId
        }

        if (delBtn !== null) {
           Confirms('Desea borrar este producto?').then(res => {
              if (res) {
                 axios.delete(`/dashboard/product/${dataRow.productId}`)
                 .then(res => {
                    table.deleteRow(dataRow.productId);
                    Notify('success', `Producto ${dataRow.productId} fue eliminado.`)
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response) {
                       Notify('error', `Deletion problem: ${error.response.data}`)
                    }
                 })
              }
           })
        }
     }
      
   })
   
})
```

The modal was created in HTML + Bootstrap 5.3.

`notify.js` is a small module I created to replace the built-in confirm() javascript method and others.

Inside each row, of this grid, there are two buttons to Edit/Delete the clicked row.
The row is loaded using its key field (productId) and the data is retrieved from the grid and stored in the `dataRow` record by calling the `row.getData()` method.

By adding the click event listener to the grid container (div tag), any click that occurs inside it can be captured and then asked for the child element that received the event.
In this way we don't need to create an event listener for each individual button inside the grid.

The event handler will also reveal us what row, in the grid, the clicked button belongs to.